# dual display X Windows configuration arm

Tags: linux, x11, display-settings, arch-arm

I am building a Linux distro (via Yocto) on an imx6 (Congatech Q7) arm (4.1 kernel, Xorg 1.18 module version 2.10.1 ) I have two 800x480 displays connected on the LVDS. I have successfully configured the hardware to run mirrored with X. It comes up and works like a champ.

I need to run the displays independent. I can bring up either one individually with X.
The hardware only has 1 graphics accelerator, so I need to use the old fashioned fb device.

If I do not bring up X I can copy images back and forth from the fb devices (fb0 and fb2) successfully. So I am pretty sure the devices are okay.

When I configure the fbdev (using the same options as I had with the acceleration for size. It reports a size of 211x127. The size is 800x480.

I have run into a dead on on what to look at next, I am hoping someone in the community has run into this before.

[3254904.461] (II) VIVANTE(0): Setting screen physical size to 211 x 127

Snippet of the Xorg.0.log

```
[3254904.080] (II) VIVANTE(0): [drm] Using the DRM lock SAREA also for drawables
[3254904.080] (II) VIVANTE(0): [drm] framebuffer handle = 0x44800000            
[3254904.080] (II) VIVANTE(0): [drm] added 1 reserved context for kernel        
[3254904.080] (II) VIVANTE(0): X context handle = 0x1                           
[3254904.080] (II) VIVANTE(0): [drm] installed DRM signal handler               
[3254904.081] (II) VIVANTE(0): [DRI] installation complete                      
[3254904.081] (--) RandR disabled                                               
[3254904.118] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable                          
[3254904.118] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering                       
[3254904.460] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer                      
[3254904.461] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast                         
[3254904.461] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0          
[3254904.461] (II) VIVANTE(0): Setting screen physical size to 211 x 127
```

My xorg.conf file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "fbB"
    Driver      "fb"
    Option      "fbdev"     "/dev/fb0"
    Option      "vivante_fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
    Option      "HWcursor"  "false"
    Screen 1
EndSection
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "fbA"
    Driver      "vivante"
    Option      "fbdev"     "/dev/fb2"
    Option      "vivante_fbdev" "/dev/fb2"
    Option      "HWcursor"  "false"
    Screen 0
EndSection


Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "MonAlpha"
        Modeline "U:800x480p-59"   33.26  800 840 968 1056  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync -csync
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "MonBeta"
        Modeline "U:800x480p-59"   33.26  800 840 968 1056  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync -csync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "ScreenAlpha"
    Monitor "MonAlpha"
    Device "fbA"
    Subsection "Display"
        Modes "U:800x480p-59"       
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "ScreenBeta"
    Monitor "MonBeta"
        Device "fbB"
    Subsection "Display"
        Modes "U:800x480p-59"       
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier "Main Layout"
        Screen     0 "ScreenAlpha"  
    Screen  1 "ScreenBeta" Absolute 0 480

EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "BlankTime"  "0"
    Option "StandbyTime"  "0"
    Option "SuspendTime"  "0"
    Option "OffTime"  "0"
EndSection
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in a [closed source driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_graphics_device_driver#Vivante). So I'd contact Vivante and ask for support ...